# I am getting the following errors and warnings in my code and I am not sure as to why

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, autocad-plugin, modifier

I am using Microsoft Visual Studios, C#, and .NET.
This is my code

```
using System.IO;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;

[CommandMethod("OpenDrawing", CommandFlags.Session)]

 public static void OpenDrawing()
{
    string strFileName = "C:\\DRAFT.dwg";
    DocumentCollection acDocMgr = Application.DocumentManager;

    if (File.Exists(strFileName))
        {
            acDocMgr.Open(strFileName, false);
        }
        else
        {
            acDocMgr.MdiActiveDocument.Editor.WriteMessage("File " + strFileName +
                                                            " does not exist.");
        }
    }
```

When I try to run my code I get an error for public that says "CS0106: The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item.
I also get a warning for OpenDrawing that says "CS8321: The local function 'OpenDrawing' is declared but never used.

I am pretty new to using C#, so any feedback would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Was your intention to place this method inside a class? Because you haven't so you seem to be accidentally working with top-level statements instead.

Answer (score 1):

The method is written as a [top-level statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements). The [methods documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) says this:

> In an application that uses top-level statements, the `Main` method is generated by the compiler and contains all top-level statements.

This means that `OpenDrawing` is effectively a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) within the compiler-generated `Main` method. This causes an error because local functions can't have [access modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers).

This can be fixed by placing the method in a class (and preferably a namespace):

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        // your OpenDrawing declaration here
    }
}
```

It can then be called as `MyClass.OpenDrawing`. This class should be kept in its own file with the same name as the class (i.e. `MyClass.cs` in the example) to keep the code organized.