# How can I add a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console, autocad

I am getting an error on my code that says "Error   CS5001
Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"
I am coding in C# using Microsoft Visual Studio and .NET. This is my code.

```
    using System.IO;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
using System;






class projectsummer
{
    [CommandMethod("OpenDrawing", CommandFlags.Session)]
   

    public static void OpenDrawing()

    

    {
        string strFileName = "C:\\DRAFT.dwg";
        DocumentCollection acDocMgr = Application.DocumentManager;

        if (File.Exists(strFileName))
        {
            acDocMgr.Open(strFileName, false);
        }
        else
        {
            acDocMgr.MdiActiveDocument.Editor.WriteMessage("File " + strFileName +
                                                            " does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to go about this error. Thank you!

Comment: Did you have a Main method before which you erased? Do you know what a Main method looks likes?

Comment: What type of application is this, Console, class library, something else? You've tagged this post "dll", so _should_ it be a class library?

Comment: Wrong project type, look [here](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-43564EB9-F843-4771-823C-573495EE23E0).

Comment: I apologize, the application is a Console

Comment: Console apps need an entrypoint. Are you _sure_ it should be a console app? Where did your original Main method go?

Comment: I am trying to create a code that can open a drawing file (.dwg) in AutoCAD. I am really new to C# and using this stuff, but have been finding resources online to go from. I am trying to get this code to allow me to open a .dwg file to open into AutoCAD. My first approach was to do a class library, but now I am creating a Console application.

Comment: I think I understand what's going on now. As a double check, what's the name of the file where this posted code is stored in? "Program.cs"?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this post and your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72995802), let's try and break down what's going on.

1. You created a new Console application in Visual Studio. You did not tick "Do not use top level statements". This gave you a Program.cs file that was essentially empty (there was no "Main" method visible).
2. You erased the Hello World code given to you, and went to make a static method - the code from your previous question.
3. [Damien_The_Unbeliever commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72995802/i-am-getting-the-following-errors-and-warnings-in-my-code-and-i-am-not-sure-as-t#comment128926188_72995802) that based on the error, you put your method inside a "top level statement" file, and to put your method inside a class.
4. You wrap your method (which is still inside Program.cs) in a class, and now suddenly you get a Can't Find Entry Point error.

---

User [Ryan Pattillo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72998041) posted a great explanation of the original issue - where your method was "by itself" in the Program.cs file. You should follow their advice, but you should also ensure that this class **is in its own file.**

You should end up with this:

Program.cs

```
// this is the entire contents of the file
using ConsoleApp1;

ProjectSummer.OpenDrawing();
```

ProjectSummer.cs

```
using System.IO;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class ProjectSummer
    {
        [CommandMethod("OpenDrawing", CommandFlags.Session)]
        public static void OpenDrawing()
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Change `ConsoleApp1` to the name of your project.

The *entry point* of your application, which right now is the only file that has "top level statements", remains Program.cs, thus you fix the Can't Find Entry Point error.

---

Another adjustment you can make, which seeing you're new to C# might be useful, is to not use top level statements at all. Modify your Program.cs to this:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        // this is your program's entry point
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            ProjectSummer.OpenDrawing();
        }
    }
}
```

Change `ConsoleApp1` to the name of your project.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the AutoCAD .NET API out of process. To be able to use the AutoCAD .NET libraries, you have to build a "class library" project (DLL) and NETLOAD this DLL from a running AutoCAD process. See [this topic](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-C8C65D7A-EC3A-42D8-BF02-4B13C2EA1A4B) about in-process vs out-of-process and you can start from [this other one](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-BA686431-C8BF-49F2-946E-9CEB2F7AE4FA) to see how to create an AutoCAD .NET project.